# Where can I suggest something to Ubuntu devs?

Tags: bittorrent, signature, pgp, sha256sum

Ubuntu torrent downloads should include the PGP signature and the SHA256SUM. That would guarantee that the PGP signature and the S256SUM (current available at releases.ubuntu.com) aren't tampered.

Comment: "That would guarantee that the PGP signature and the S256SUM (current available at releases.ubuntu.com) aren't tampered." Sure but so does matching it from the ISO against the official website after downloading the ISO so adding them to the torrent is not needed.

Comment: What if the site is tampered too?

Comment: If the site were compromised, then the torrent link likely would also point to a compromised seed.

Comment: Depending on your level of trust, [torrents already include verification of file integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549004/does-bittorrent-verify-files-integrity).